# Spark stage taking too long - 2 executors doing "all" the work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

I've been trying to figure this out for the past day, but have not been successful.

### Problem I am facing

I'm reading a parquet file that is about 2GB big. The initial read is 14 partitions, then eventually gets split into 200 partitions. I perform seemingly simple SQL query that runs for 25+ mins runtime, about 22 mins is spent on a single stage. Looking in the Spark UI, I see that all computation is eventually pushed to about 2 to 4 executors, with lots of shuffling. I don't know what is going on. Please I would appreciate any help.

### Setup

- **Spark environment** - Databricks
- **Cluster mode** - Standard
- **Databricks Runtime Version** - 6.4 ML (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)
- **Cloud** - Azure
- **Worker Type** - 56 GB, 16 cores per machine. Minimum 2 machines
- **Driver Type** - 112 GB, 16 cores

### Notebook

#### Cell 1: Helper functions

```r
load_data = function(path, type) {
  input_df = read.df(path, type)

  input_df = withColumn(input_df, "dummy_col", 1L)
  createOrReplaceTempView(input_df, "__current_exp_data")

  ## Helper function to run query, then save as table
  transformation_helper = function(sql_query, destination_table) {
    createOrReplaceTempView(sql(sql_query), destination_table)
  }

  ## Transformation 0: Calculate max date, used for calculations later on
  transformation_helper(
    "SELECT 1L AS dummy_col, MAX(Date) max_date FROM __current_exp_data",
    destination_table = "__max_date"
  )

  ## Transformation 1: Make initial column calculations
  transformation_helper(
    "
    SELECT
        cId                                                          AS cId
      , date_format(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')                              AS Date
      , date_format(DateEntered, 'yyyy-MM-dd')                       AS DateEntered
      , eId

      , (CASE WHEN isnan(tSec) OR isnull(tSec) THEN 0 ELSE tSec END) AS tSec
      , (CASE WHEN isnan(eSec) OR isnull(eSec) THEN 0 ELSE eSec END) AS eSec

      , approx_count_distinct(eId) OVER (PARTITION BY cId)           AS dc_eId
      , COUNT(*)                   OVER (PARTITION BY cId, Date)     AS num_rec

      , datediff(Date, DateEntered)                                  AS analysis_day
      , datediff(max_date, DateEntered)                              AS total_avail_days
    FROM __current_exp_data
    CROSS JOIN __max_date ON __main_data.dummy_col = __max_date.dummy_col
  ",
    destination_table = "current_exp_data_raw"
  )

  ## Transformation 2: Drop row if Date is not valid
  transformation_helper(
    "
    SELECT 
        cId
      , Date
      , DateEntered
      , eId
      , tSec
      , eSec

      , analysis_day
      , total_avail_days
      , CASE WHEN analysis_day     == 0 THEN 0    ELSE floor((analysis_day - 1) / 7)   END AS week
      , CASE WHEN total_avail_days  < 7 THEN NULL ELSE floor(total_avail_days / 7) - 1 END AS avail_week
    FROM current_exp_data_raw
    WHERE 
        isnotnull(Date) AND 
        NOT isnan(Date) AND 
        Date >= DateEntered AND
        dc_eId == 1 AND
        num_rec == 1
  ",
    destination_table = "main_data"
  )
  
  cacheTable("main_data_raw")
  cacheTable("main_data")
}

spark_sql_as_data_table = function(query) {
  data.table(collect(sql(query)))
}

get_distinct_weeks = function() {
  spark_sql_as_data_table("SELECT week FROM current_exp_data GROUP BY week")
}
```

#### Cell 2: Call helper function that triggers the long running task

```r
library(data.table)
library(SparkR)

spark = sparkR.session(sparkConfig = list())

load_data_pq("/mnt/public-dir/file_0000000.parquet")

set.seed(1234)

get_distinct_weeks()
```

### Long running stage DAG

[image: Long running stage DAG]

### Stats about long running stage

[image: Executor stats]

### Logs

I trimmed it down, and show only entries that appeared multiple times below

```
BlockManager: Found block rdd_22_113 locally

CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 812

ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray: Reached spill threshold of 4096 rows, switching to org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter

InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate (dc_eId#61L = 1) generates partition filter: ((dc_eId.lowerBound#622L <= 1) && (1 <= dc_eId.upperBound#621L))

InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate (num_rec#62L = 1) generates partition filter: ((num_rec.lowerBound#627L <= 1) && (1 <= num_rec.upperBound#626L))

InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate isnotnull(Date#57) generates partition filter: ((Date.count#599 - Date.nullCount#598) > 0)

InMemoryTableScanExec: Predicate isnotnull(DateEntered#58) generates partition filter: ((DateEntered.count#604 - DateEntered.nullCount#603) > 0)

MemoryStore: Block rdd_17_104 stored as values in memory (estimated size <VERY SMALL NUMBER &lt; 10> MB, free 10.0 GB)

ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 200 non-empty blocks including 176 local blocks and 24 remote blocks

ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 4 remote fetches in 1 ms

UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 254 spilling sort data of <Between 1 and 3 GB> to disk (3  times so far)
```

Comment: there might be skew in the data that you are processing. Based on the description it is definitely skewed. But from the details it hard to tell what is making the data skewed.

Comment: try doing coalesce or repartition on your df and see if that improves the performance. Doing repartition will distribute your data evenly on all the partitions based on the number of partitions you provide and that could solve your skewing issue.

Comment: Which transformation is taking longer - transformation1 or transformation2?

Comment: @nag00d, Transformation 1 seems to be the culprit

Comment: @nag00d, Actually, I can't tell... The only DAG I could get is the one I have in the OP. It seens transformation 1 and 2 are mixed into a single stage

Comment: Looks like it is scanning "current_exp_data" and "current_exp_data_raw" tables, but I can't figure out which action triggered the transformations. It can't be get_distinct_weeks().

Comment: `get_distinct_weeks` calls `collect` action. I've been debugging this further and I think I noticed a few things.

(1) The cacheTable calls adds some time to the calculations. (2) The filtering in `Transformation 2` tends to take a while also, that is very weird to me